# creating a type which can be initialized with assignment, but is not copyable

Tags: c++

I am looking to create a type which can be initialized with assignment from another type, but cannot be copied. The idea is similar to that of a scoped smart pointer in that I want the object of this type to own a resource for its lifetime, but I also want to be able to use assignment syntax. So in synopsis, this is what I want:

```
T x = new U; // allowed
T y(new U);  // allowed
T z = x;     // not allowed
T x2(x)      // not allowed
```

This is what I have tried so far...

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

class U {};

class T : boost::noncopyable {
public:
    T(U *p) : p_(p) {
    }

    ~T() {
        delete p_;
    }

    operator bool() const { return p_ != 0; }

private:
    U *p_;
};

int main() {
    T x = new U; // allowed
    T y(new U);  // allowed
    //T z = x;     // not allowed
    //T x2(x)      // not allowed
}
```

which unfortunately results in an error:

> $ g++ test.cc -o test /usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp: In copy
>   constructor 'T::T(const T&)': /usr/include/boost/noncopyable.hpp:27:7:
>   error: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const
>   boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable&)' is private test.cc:6:30: error:
>   within this context test.cc: In function 'int main()': test.cc:20:12:
>   note: synthesized method 'T::T(const T&)' first required here

**NOTE: C++11's move features are a non-option for me, as this must be able to be compiled with a relatively old version of gcc that does not have C++11 support.**

Because of the lack of C++11 support, I am not sure there is a "good" solution. But I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Just make the copy constructor private.

Comment: @Chris: you have not read my question, the copy constructor already **is** private. That's what `boost::noncopyable` does. I need it to be non-copyable, but I also want it to be initializable with assignment syntax.

Comment: `T y = x` where `x` isn't a `T` is the same as `T y(T(x))` IIRC (**not** `T y(x)`), so you have to have the copy constructor public if you want to allow this pre C++11

Comment: @SethCarnegie, although copy elision is perhaps allowed to take place?

Comment: Seth is correct, `T x = y;` is the specific syntax for *copy initialization* (and has *nothing* to do with assignment, btw).

Comment: @Seth: this is what I feared, but figured I'd ask to see if anyone has any clever solutions. Currently I'm simulating what I want in a way that is similar to `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @eq- even if copy elision takes place, the copy constructor has to be accessible, compiler optimisations can't circumvent language rules

Comment: @Seth: Also, I recommend making your comment an answer so it is possible to accept it if no one can give a better answer. Which I suspect is that case :-).

Comment: @SethCarnegie, yes (that's implied by not necessitating it.)

Comment: @eq- oh, I thought you were implying that this was supposed to work even if the copy constructor is private if the copy is elided, sorry.

Comment: @EvanTeran Doesn't `auto_ptr` not work with the `=` syntax? I thought you had to use the `()` syntax to initialise a copy, no? If it does allow that, then just look at the source and see how it does it and post an answer.

Comment: @Seth: you are correct, my solution is not **exactly** like `auto_ptr`. I use a factory function to create the objects (using normal constructor syntax) and then, I use `auto_ptr` like trickery to transfer ownership when the result of the function is assigned. My end goal is to be able to write: `if(T x = create_T()) {`

Comment: As a note for clarification, I consider it fair game to have `create_T` return a pointer to an object which can be used to construct a `T`, like in my original example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding from comments is correct - you want something like that:

```
U* create_T() { return new U; }
if (T t = create_T())
{
  // do something with t
}
```

The problem here, already mentioned in comments: this syntax `T t = u` is just calling copy constructor. If u is of type `T` it is equivalent to: `T t(u)`. If `u`, like in your example, is of another type convertible to `T` (`here by T::T(U*)`) then it is actually this: `T t(T(u))`. So here you have the copy contructor for which compiler complains.

There is no solution, because this is not valid `if` syntax:

```
if (T i(create_T())) {}
```

However I would not write all of these without good advise ;)

You can forget about problems with copy constructor with this syntax:

```
if (U* u = create_T()) {
   T t(u);
   ....
}
```

BTW, `std::auto_ptr` has the same problem as your `T` type. Just add explicit to your `T(U*)` constructor and you will see similarity to `auto_ptr`:

```
class U {};

class T : boost::noncopyable {
public:
    explicit T(U *p) : p_(p) {
    }

    ~T() {
        delete p_;
    }

private:
    U *p_;
};

int main() {
    T x = new U; // allowed
    T y(new U);  // allowed
    std::auto_ptr<U> a = new U;
    std::auto_ptr<U> b(new U);
}
```

Results in:

```
prog.cpp:25: error: conversion from ‘U*’ to non-scalar type ‘T’ requested
prog.cpp:27: error: conversion from ‘U*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::auto_ptr<U>’ requested
```

Here my [ideone](http://ideone.com/jz3RT) study...

Comment: @Evan, BTW - will it work for you: `if (U* u = create_T()) { T t(u);}`? If not - write copy constructor. You can make `p_` mutable to take ownership from copied const object.

Comment: your suggestion will definitely "work". The syntax is not quite what I would like, but it does achieve the basic concept of what I wanted, so you get a +1. I'm going to leave the question open for a little while to see if anyone comes up with something clever :-).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if it is clever - but look at my ideone link. I added new solution with mutable p_ and InitT struct. However this breaks your goal not to allow copy construction...

Comment: @EvanTeran Hello again. You see I remembered this question and I have feeling that this would work: `for (T t(create_T()); t;) { ...; break; }`. for-loop is the only one with does not have this limitation with constructing variable with "constructor-way".