# Why "constructor-way" of declaring variable in "for-loop" allowed but in "if-statement" not allowed?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, language-lawyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't variables defined in a conditional be constructed with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332285/why-cant-variables-defined-in-a-conditional-be-constructed-with-arguments)

Consider this simple example:

```
/*1*/ int main() {
/*2*/   for (int i(7); i;){break;} 
/*3*/   if (int i(7)) {}
/*4*/ }
```

Why line-2 compiles just fine, whilst line-3 gives the error? This is little strange to me why if-statement is in this aspect treated worse than for-loop?

If this is compiler specific - I tested with [gcc-4.5.1](http://ideone.com/RkJuE):

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:3:7: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
>   prog.cpp:3:7: error: expected ')' before 'int'

I was inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655284/defining-a-variable-in-the-condition-part-of-an-if-statement)

[UPDATE]

I know this compiles just fine:

```
/*1*/ int main() {
/*2*/   for (int i = 7; i;){break;} 
/*3*/   if (int i = 7) {}
/*4*/ }
```

[UPDATE2]

It seems to be purely academic question - but this could be extremely important for such types as `std::unique_ptr<>` which cannot be copied:

```
#include <memory>
int main() {
  if (std::unique_ptr<int> i = new (std::nothrow) int(7)) {
  }
  if (std::unique_ptr<int> i(new (std::nothrow) int(7))) {
  }
}
```

Neither of these two kinds are allowed. Not sure about new C++11 syntax `{}`?

Comment: Clang is more specific about this: "Test.cpp:3:18: error: variable declaration in condition cannot have a parenthesized initializer". So yeah, it seems to be disallowed. MSVC++ 2012 just gives three distinct syntax errors, seems to be completely unaware of the 'problem', like g++ :-)

Comment: The basic problem is that the C++ standard does not allow it.  At issue, most likely, is the scope of the variable; presumably, it would have to be the `if` body and the `else` body.  There's no particularly obvious reason why it couldn't be done; it just hasn't been proposed to the committee, proven in prototypes, and demonstrated to be a useful addition to the language.  If you do `if`, you'd presumably need to accommodate the same change in `while` and `switch` too, wouldn't you?

Comment: MSVC++ 2010 also gives three syntax errors, but IntelliSense curiously reports "a function type is not allowed here".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The C++ standard *does* allow variable declarations in `if`/`while`/`switch`. And yes, the variable's scope includes both the `if` and the `else` statement. The problem at hand is why the standard disallows calling the constructor using the `()` notation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd be happy with `while` and `switch` too :D See my update - with `std::unique_ptr` this is no longer just academic question....

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "*this could be extremely important for such types as `std::unique_ptr<>` which cannot be copied:*" How could that *ever* be false? The only way it would be false is if `new` failed. Which means it threw an exception. Which means you're not in that code anymore. And if you use `new(nothrow)` or turn off exception handling, you can just create the `unique_ptr` and test it *afterwards*. It doesn't have to go into the `if` clause. You don't need to copy it to *test* it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I just forgot about `std::nothrow` - of course I meant nothrow version - thanks for pointing out me this. Anyway - the problem is that this syntax does not compile. See Dietmar's answer for valid syntax. But what to do with non-copyable and non-moveable types in C++03 where `{}` constructor syntax were not allowed?

Comment: what is the point of 'if (int i = 7) {}' since it would always be true - it *is* a pure academic question where one can only guess about the design reason.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "*But what to do with non-copyable and non-moveable types in C++03 where {} constructor syntax were not allowed?*" You don't have to copy *or* move the value in order to *test* it. And that's what the condition is for: a test. In short, *stop declaring variables in a test*.

Comment: @AndersK change this to `if (int * p = new (std::nothrow) int(7)) {}` and it becomes obvious. Maybe too simple example :( See also last part about `std::unique_ptr` problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know I can stop declaring variables in test, actually I very rarely declare variables in if... Just do not know why this syntax is allowed in for-loop and not allowed in if-statement.

Comment: @JesseGood This possible dup only concentrates on if-statement. My question is why there is a difference between if-statement and for-loop in declaring variables. A little different subject in my opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't provide a rationale but I would suspect that using the constructor notation could cause some inconsistencies. For example, since function declarations aren't allowed in the `if` statement, the most vexing parse would actually mean what was intended. For example:

```
int f();        // function declaration (simple form or the most vexing parse)
if (int f()) {  // illegal in C++ but, when allowed, would be a zero-initialized int
}
```

In C++ 2011 you can use brace-initialization:

```
if (int x{f()}) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, brace-initialization doesn't always mean the same thing as using constructor notation (I think it's called *direct-initialization*).

With respect to the update: you can use one of these:

```
if (std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1))) { ... }
if (auto p = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(2))) { ... }
if (std::unique_ptr<int>{new int(3)}) { ... }
```

It seems there are plenty of options :-)

Comment: Can you comment my [UPDATE2]. I am asking about `std::unique_ptr`...

Comment: `if (std::unique_ptr<int> i{new int(7)})` would work in C++11.

Comment: There are several ways to deal with `std::unique_ptr<T>`. In all cases Where there is conceptually a move construction I would expect it to be elided.

Comment: @DietmarKühl thanks (+1 for now - I'd probably accept - just giving some time to others). However I remember question when type is not copyable and the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269438/creating-a-type-which-can-be-initialized-with-assignment-but-is-not-copyable

Comment: @PiotrNycz: If the type isn't copyable or movable you can use `T{...}` in most cases. Admittedly, this leaves a few cases where `T{...}` means something different than `T(...)` (e.g., `std::vector<int>(1, 2)` and `std::vector<int>{1, 2}` except that there isn't a problem because `std::vector<T>` is copyable or movable). I'd think the cases where you can't uses such objects as conditions in `if` but really want to are fairly rare.

Comment: @Dietmar thanks once again. Just to have fully understanding: can you give any example where this questioned syntax in if-statement could give "inconsistencies"? I just try to fully understand your first two sentences in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of syntax, the reason is simple.

The first element of the `for` statement are *statements*. Statements can create variables as well as initialize them. The `if` conditional is a *condition*. The spec does define that a condition can create a variable, but only by `=` initialization.

Be glad the spec even *allows* you to create variables in an `if` at all. It has to have special grammar to even allow that ("condition" being different from "expression"), and that was probably something inherited from C.

That being said, C++11 does define a condition as being able to initialize a declaration with a *braced-init-list* (spec-speak for "initializer list"). So it *should* be legal. But since VS2012 doesn't support initializer lists yet...

Comment: I am glad for all the things spec allows me and for your time (+1). And I am sorry that I am of this kind of people that "give him a finger and he will want the hand" - not sure how to translate this idiom to english - this is just raw translation from my native language ;)

Comment: @PiotrNycz: I think that would translate better as "give him ***a*** finger...", as giving someone "***the*** finger" has a different connotation ;)

Comment: Corrected :D BTW, It seems that english has identical idiom, probably both languages took it from some ancient source.

Comment: `The first two elements of the for statement are statements.` Shouldn't that be, `The first element of` and not `The first two elements of`. I believe the second element is a condition.

Comment: @JesseGood: Fair enough.